# NSNumber property is nil

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber

I create a NSNumber property like so,

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *repeat;
```

And from within the same class set it to a NSNumber contained in an array

```
self.repeat = [dataArray objectAtIndex:3];
```

This doesn't throw any errors during compilation or runtime. Though it still shows up in the debug area as nil. I know NSNumber is immutable, but shouldn't this still work?

**EDIT:** If I set self.repeat to a new NSNumber object, it still shows as nil.

```
self.repeat = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
```

Comment: What is value of [dataArray objectAtIndex:3] ?

Comment: How and when does it show as `nil`? Is `dataArray` `nil`?

Comment: There are valid contents (NSNumbers) in the array, but when I set the property it shows up as nil in the bottom breakpoint panel of Xcode

Comment: You cannot add nil als 4th element to dataArray (index 3). Therefore it could only be that dataArray itself is nil. Then objectAtIndex could return nil too. Or self.repeat has not been set at that point in time when you found out that it was nil.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LLSAd.png That's what my breakpoint looks like. I have it set after the code in my question

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a problem with Xcode? What happens if you add the line `NSLog(@"Repeat value: %i",[self.repeat intValue]);` after `self.repeat = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];`?

Comment: This definitely needs more code, not one line.

Comment: As @ChrisH said just nslog (or right click repeat and select display ...) the value of repeat. You could even do NSLog(@"repeat: %@", self.repeat). If that does not solve it then show more code.

Comment: It was actually an Xcode error, as @ChrisH said. I purged my derived data and had success. Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually was an Xcode error. I purged my derived data, restarted my Mac, and tried again with success.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of one of your screenshots, it looks like the object at index 3 is a BOOL. Just do this:

```
self.repeat = [NSNumber numberWithBool:[dataArray objectAtIndex:3]];
```

That's always going to return either 0 or 1 though, so take that for what you will.